# Python Numpy Get Green Mask even if pixel values aren't all 0 in other channel

Tags: python, numpy

The code below basically gets the color green from an image:

```
green_mask = np.all(label==[0,255,0], axis=-1)
```

But how do I change that line so I can still get mask even if, say the first channel contains pixels greater than 0 BUT still less than 255?

So, I want something like this:

```
green_mask = np.all((label[:,:,0]<255 and label[:,:,1]==255 and label[:,:,0]<255), axis=-1)
```

But that gives me an error: "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Use `&` and parentheses.

Comment: @Divakar Like this? green_mask = (label[:,:,0]<255 & label[:,:,1]==255 & label[:,:,0]<255) Still gives same error though. Oh wait nevermind I got it. Put parentheses in between each. Thank you!

Comment: @cmed123 add your solution as a self answer so you can help others :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was:

```
green_mask = (label[:,:,0]<255) & (label[:,:,1]==255) & (label[:,:,0]<255)
```